# This/that: a determiner or pronoun?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, pronouns, determiners

Is there commonly accepted opinion on what lexemes *this/that* are, determiners or pronouns?

E.g. in the following phrase:

> ... can help you work these out

*these* seem to show some properties of pronouns more than that of determiners.

**More generic question:** is there commonly accepted classification of the English closed class lexemes?

Comment: Why can't it be both? (i.e. the same word can play different grammatical roles in different sentences)

Comment: Or different words can have the same surface structure.

Comment: An answer about the Penn Treebank POS set is hardly an answer to the classification of _this_ and _that_. And the other question is a good one, too. Is there a decent classification of closed class lexemes?

Comment: "This/that" and the plural forms "these/those" belong to the category "demonstrative determinative", where they typically function as determiner, e.g. "this guy", "these houses". But they can also function in 'fused determiner-head constructions, which is the case in your example. In the 'fused determiner-head' construction, the head and the determiner are combined or fused into a single word -- in your example "these", where we understand "these x", where "x" is interpreted from the discourse.

Comment: Members of the closed class comprise: preposition, determinative, subordinator and coordinator. These categories do not readily accept the addition of new members.

Comment: Aren't the *modals/auxiliaries* and the *pronouns* also closed classes?

Comment: We're talking here about word categories at the topmost level, not the sub-categories. Auxiliary verb and pronoun are sub-categories of the more general categories verb and noun, which are not of course closed class.